# update generic entity in linq to object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function written in linq to sql

```
public static bool update(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate,Action<T> setter)
        {
            try
            {
                Context myContext = new Context ();
                T updateObject;
                updateObject = myContext.GetTable<T>().Where(predicate).First();
                setter(updateObject);
                nhagoDb.SubmitChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

but i dont know how to write this in linq to object, especially there's no method like `GetTable<T>().Where(predicate).First();`

please help
many thanks :)

Comment: Linq to objects works against an in-memory collection. What is you in-memory collection?

Comment: I'd change that Where(p).First() into a Single(p) to make sure you are updating one record and on record only,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that such a method is even necessary in LINQ to objects. Your code can simply do the work itself. E.g.

```
var myObject = myList.First(x => x.Something);
myObject.UpdateSomething(newValue);
// or just:
myList.First(x => x.Something).UpdateSomething(newValue);
```

If you did want a method to do this, it would be called like:

```
myList.Update(x => x.Something, x => x.UpdateSomething(newValue));
```

The former is shorter, clearer (IMO), and faster than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement myContext.GetTable() yourself. Create an extension method for Context class. 
Inside the method use reflection to find the db set whith type T and return it, the rest of your code will work